# Kotlin RegEx Space works but not Word Boundary

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have to process some text that ends in a date, and I'm trying to extract the individual parts using Kotlin RegEx. I can get this to work with a `space`, but not with a word boundary `\b`.

**Working Code:**

```
val name = "Prefix Text Sept 7 2007"
var regex = Regex("""(?<prefix>.*?)\b(?<month>Sept|September) (?<day>\d{1,2}) (?<year>\d{2,4})""")
var matched = regex.matchEntire(name)
println("Prefix: ${matched!!.groups["prefix"]?.value}")
println("Month: ${matched!!.groups["month"]?.value}")
println("Day: ${matched!!.groups["day"]?.value}")
println("Year: ${matched!!.groups["year"]?.value}")
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Prefix: Prefix Text 
Month: Sept
Day: 7
Year: 2007
```

If I replace the second line with:

```
var regex = Regex("""(?<prefix>.*?)\b(?<month>Sept|September)\b(?<day>\d{1,2})\b(?<year>\d{2,4})""")
```

I don't get a match. This just replaces the `space` before the day and the year with a `\b`. I would like to understand why this second attempt does not match.

Comment: Word boundary matches a *location* in the string, it does not match any whitespace.

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, which is zero-length. If there's a white space there (or any character), the pattern won't match.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure why this question is closed. The discussion in the other question relates to the minus sign - being a non-word character and hence regarded as a word boundary. Here, a white space character is a word boundary, so the second RegEx should have worked. The other question does not answer my problem here.

Comment: As explained above, I would like to have this question re-opened.